# Why does $H^0(\mathcal{O}_C(m))=H^0(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(md))$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, curves

Let C be a projective curve. In reading Harris’ work I often come across statements that seem to rely on the follow fact:

$H^0(C,\mathcal{O}_C(m))=H^0(\mathbb{P}^1,\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(md))$, where the numbers in the parantheses refer to taking those degrees.

I have two questions:

(1) Are more restrictions on C necessary (other than just being projective)?

(2) Why is this the case?

Comment: You need more detail about the setup. Is it a degree $d$ cover $C \to \mathbb P^1$?

Comment: I think you can probably find a proof in Chapter 3 or 4 in Hartshorne (don't have my copy with me) but *very* roughly, this result is saying that degree $md$ polynomials on $\mathbb{P}^1$ are the same as degree $m$ polynomials on $C$, for certain degree $d$ curves $C$.